# async/await promise logic issues

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I am in the process of learning how to use async/await with promises. I am having a few issues with the first promise. Specifically:

```
var pres = mvc.Components.get("search1");
pres.data('results', {
  count: 0,
  output_mode: 'json_rows'
}).on("data", function(results) {
  alldata3 = results._data;
  console.log(alldata3)
});
```

I am pulling results from a function within another script. The result for 'search1' is very large. It takes longer then search two for instance. The issue I am having is that it does not wait until 'results._data' has fully been assigned to alldata3 to move on to itVolTwo(). This ends up giving me an async error indicating 'alldata3.rows' is undefined. Is there anyway to rework this so it waits until it receives the full results from search1? Whats the best course of action here? Thanks for any help!

```
var alldata3 = new Object();
var alldata32 = new Object();
// Promise
const itVolOne = new Promise(
  (resolve, reject) => {
    if (boolpool) {
      var pres = mvc.Components.get("search1");
      pres.data('results', {
        count: 0,
        output_mode: 'json_rows'
      }).on("data", function(results) {
        alldata3 = results._data;
        console.log(alldata3)
      });
      console.log(alldata3)
      var rdbms1 = mvc.Components.get("search2");
      rdbms1.data('results', {
        count: 0,
        output_mode: 'json_rows'
      }).on("data", function(results) {
        alldata32 = results._data;
        console.log(alldata32)
      });
      console.log(alldata32)

      console.log(alldata3, alldata32)
      resolve(alldata3, alldata32)
    } else {
      const reason = new Error('Unable to get the datas');
      reject(reason);
    }
  }
);

var rdbmsData = new Object();
async function itVolTwo() {
  return new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
      for await (let row of alldata3.rows) {
        rdbmsData[row[0]] = {
          "crit": row[1],
          "high": row[2],
          "med": row[3],
          "low": row[4]
        }
      }
      console.log(rdbmsData)
      resolve(rdbmsData);
    }
  );
};

// 2nd promise
var presData = new Object();
async function itVolThree() {
  return new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
      for await (let row of alldata32.rows) {
        presData[row[0]] = {
          "crit": row[1],
          "high": row[2],
          "med": row[3],
          "low": row[4]
        }
      }
      console.log(presData)
      resolve(presData);
    }
  );
};
// 3rd promise
var endData = new Object();
async function itVolFour() {
  return new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
      function sum(a, b) {
        Object.keys(b).forEach(k => {
          if (b[k] && typeof b[k] === 'object') return sum(a[k] = a[k] || {}, b[k]);
          a[k] = (+a[k] || 0) + +b[k];
        });
        return a;
      }
      endData = [rdbmsData, presData].reduce(sum);
      console.log(endData)
      resolve(endData);
    }
  );
};
// call our promise
async function itInit() {
  try {
    console.log('I got to the call YEY!');

    let stepOne = await itVolOne;
    let stepTwo = await itVolTwo();
    let stepThree = await itVolThree();
    let stepFour = await itVolFour();

    console.log(endData);
    console.log('Done');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('u done f'
      ed up ');
    }
  }

  (async() => {
    await itInit();
  })();
```

Comment: `return new Promise(async (resolve, reject)` ... that always smells ... since the Promise executor returns a Promise, that suggests you don't actually need to construct a Promise in the first place if you already have Promises you're working with .... to be honest, it looks like you've looked at all the latest tools (`async/await` and `for await of`, etc) and decided to use these tools regardless if they fit the job or not ... don't use a brand new cordless drill with RGB lighting to hammer in a nail

Comment: So I understand my script is not very good. I need to work on that. But where I am stuck right now is the first part. How to wait for results of the first 'search1' before continuing on to another function with a for loop.

Comment: To add to this, I did a bit of research and using async await was recommended by many as the proper way to get the sequence down. If there is another tool or method you would suggest I am all ears. The logic of structuring pulling that first data and then running it through my loops to return the final result(endData) is what gets me.

Comment: sorry, I didn't say async/await is NOT the right tool - it just looks that way, because `async` Promise executor never makes sense - I haven't looked into you code enough to make any more judgement on it, purely due to that

Comment: I added the async for the promise executor as more of a guess and check type deal. The 'for await of' was giving me issues even though it is within a async function.

Comment: You say that `alldata3` isn't "fully" assigned. Does this mean that the "data" event is called multiple times to return data a bit at a time? If so, you need to tell us what API/Framework you're using there. It almost definitely has some way of indicating when the data transfer is complete, and we can't really help you unless we know what that is.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that incorrect. 'search1' takes a bit to run and has a much larger amount of results to return. I am writing this inside of the require function of a splunk HTML dashboard using the web framework. A example dashboard with the SplunkJS stack can be seen here: http://dev.splunk.com/view/webframework-codeexamples/SP-CAAAEVV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should 'promisify' the event emitter objects (something.data.on), and then you can await the results:

```
  const itVolOne = async () => {
    if (boolpool) {
        const pres = mvc.Components.get("search1");
        const alldata3 = await new Promise(resolve => {
             pres.data('results', {count: 0, output_mode: 'json_rows'}).on("data",
               results => {
                   resolve(results._data);
               }
             );
        });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(alldata3));

        const rdbms1 = mvc.Components.get("search2");
        const alldata32 = await new Promise(resolve => {
           rdbms1.data('results', {count: 0, output_mode: 'json_rows'}).on("data",
             results => {
                resolve(results._data);
             }
           );
        });

        console.log(JSON.stringify(alldata32));

        return { alldata3, alldata32 }
    } else {
       throw new Error('Unable to get the datas');
    }
  }
```

So, now the itVolOne function returns all the results in a "synchronized way" and the remaining functions can be rewritten:

```
  const itVolTwo =  alldata3 => {
      return alldata3.rows.reduce((rdbmsData, row) => {
          rdbmsData[row[0]] = {
            "crit": row[1],
            "high": row[2],
            "med":  row[3], 
            "low":  row[4]
          };

          return rdbmsData;
      }, {});
  }

  const itVolThree = alldata32 => {
     return alldata32.rows.reduce((presData, row) => {
          presData[row[0]] = {
             "crit": row[1],
             "high": row[2],
             "med":  row[3], 
             "low":  row[4]
          };
          return presData;
     }, {});
  }

  const itVolFour = (rdbmsData, presData) => {
     function sum(a, b) {
        Object.keys(b).forEach(k => {
            if (b[k] && typeof b[k] === 'object') return sum(a[k] = a[k] || {}, b[k]);
            a[k] = (+a[k] || 0) + +b[k];
        });
        return a;
      }
      return [rdbmsData, presData].reduce(sum);
  }
```

Now you can await only in the first step:

```
  async function itInit() {
    try {
        console.log('I got to the call YEY!');

        const { alldata3, alldata32 } = await itVolOne();
        const stepTwo = itVolTwo(alldata3);
        const stepThree = itVolThree(alldata32);
        const endData = itVolFour(stepTwo, stepThree);

        console.log(JSON.stringify(endData));
        console.log('Done');
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log('u done f\'ed up');
    }
  }
```

And call the main function:

```
itInit();
```

That's all.

Comment: So reading after saying that I have seen the following used before:.search.on("search:done", function(state, job) {
if (state.content.resultCount === 0) {
alert("no results");
}
}); So to clarify your 'promisify' statement, I could use 'search.on.done'? sorry for the confusion. Not much documentation on this stuff for the environment I'm in. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Nevermind. i got it working. Adding the listener for the done callback on itInit(); fixed it:

`search1.on('search:done', function(properties) {
itInit();
        });`

Comment: To understand the 'promisify' structure you can read this: https://hackernoon.com/how-to-stop-using-callbacks-and-start-living-1e5ed92e68e8 and https://finecoding.org/promisified-events-using-the-facade-pattern-b0b788806cdc

Comment: Mauro, after reviewing this code and analyzing it to fully understand I have found itVolFour is not adding the values of step two and three. I am unsure of what the issue is. the output of itVolFour is just what "rdbmsData' contains. When writing it out in a normal function not in the chain like this it adds(merges)/appends the two objects.

Comment: I rewrite the previous code here: https://jsfiddle.net/mastepanoski/rs8jLqf3/5/. I simulated a possible input so you can define your own inputs and the expected output. I did not check the itVolFour function, the params are received, so the problem should be in the implementation of itVolFoul.